# How to add an image to a jinja html page

Tags: html, django, jinja2

I'm just learning the basics of django and jinja. I've extended my header file and now I want to add an image to the page, but I don't know the jinja syntax for doing that. Please assist.

```
{% extends "media/header.html" %}
{% block content %}
This is where I would like to insert my image.
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use html `img` tag for that. If you pass your image in context as variable;

```
{% extends "media/header.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <img src="{{ variable }}" alt="image alt text" />
{% endblock %}
```

If you just have static path;

```
{% extends "media/header.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <img src="{{ static('path/to/image.png') }}" alt="image alt text" />
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the static path, but got a 'pass the remainder' error. I moved the quote to include 'static' and it ran ok, but the image did not display. Please explain how to pass an image as variable.

Comment: If you got that error, you are not using Jinja at all, but Django template language.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is too late to reply, but this is how I use for rendering images using jinja syntax. I have successfully rendered images on pdf from html.

```
 <div class="img-div" style="background-image: url('{{ element.image }}');">
 </div>
```

`element.image` could be a any resolvable url.